# What are those "white eggs" in doner kebab? (picture attached)

Tags: meat, beef, lamb, turkish-cuisine, kebab

I bought some doner kebab from the supermarket, and it is pre-cooked. When I re-heat it using oven, I found many white round spots/particles, the size is about 3mm to 5mm in diameter. I attach some pictures below. Figure.1 is from refrigerator before putting into oven. Figure.2 is after baking by oven. Figure.3 and Figure.4 are the pack of container. First I thought it might be fat, but it seems not, because the texture is different from the fat in the ground meat. Also if I  take those white particles out and press it, there is no oil from it. So I think it is not fat. Are those worm eggs?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s not “eggs”. Those are bits of cartilage and connective tissue that were ground up with the rest of the meat.

Comment: In other words… don't buy that one again:/ 57% fat too.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sure it’s 57% fat, but only 55 calories per 100g!

Comment: @Sneftel, the 55 is a mistake.  It is actually 550.